# Looking for a deviation from a pattern in R

Tags: r, loops

Hoping to find a solution to this problem here.

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
sample <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
), id2 = c("test_0001", "test_0001", "test_0001", "test_001", 
"test_001", "test 0001", "test001", "test_0001", "test_0001", 
"test_0002", "test_0002", "test_0002", "test_0002", "test_0002", 
"test_002", "test_002", "test_00003", "test_0003", "test_00003", 
"test_0003", "test 00003", "test_00004", "test_00004", "test_00004", 
"test_00004", "test_0004", "test_0004", "test_00004")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))

#    id        id2
# 1   1  test_0001
# 2   2  test_0001
# 3   3  test_0001
# 4   4   test_001
# 5   5   test_001
# 6   6  test 0001
# 7   7    test001
# 8   8  test_0001
# 9   9  test_0001
# 10 10  test_0002
# 11 11  test_0002
# 12 12  test_0002
# 13 13  test_0002
# 14 14  test_0002
# 15 15   test_002
# 16 16   test_002
# 17 17 test_00003
# 18 18  test_0003
# 19 19 test_00003
# 20 20  test_0003
# 21 21 test 00003
# 22 22 test_00004
# 23 23 test_00004
# 24 24 test_00004
# 25 25 test_00004
# 26 26  test_0004
# 27 27  test_0004
# 28 28 test_00004
```

I want to test if the suffix (last 4 digits) match within each group, e.g. for the group ending in _0002, ids 15 and 16 have a deviation from the expected pattern in the prefix that is "_0002".

can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is the suffix, then we can do a grouping by the numeric part extracted and then check for number of distinct elements in the suffix digits part

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
sample %>%
   group_by(grp = readr::parse_number(id2)) %>% 
  mutate(id3 = str_remove(id2, "\\D+")) %>%        
  filter(n_distinct(substr(id3, nchar(id3)-3, nchar(id3))) == 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
      id id2          grp id3  
   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>
 1    17 test_00003     3 00003
 2    18 test_0003      3 0003 
 3    19 test_00003     3 00003
 4    20 test_0003      3 0003 
 5    21 test 00003     3 00003
 6    22 test_00004     4 00004
 7    23 test_00004     4 00004
 8    24 test_00004     4 00004
 9    25 test_00004     4 00004
10    26 test_0004      4 0004 
11    27 test_0004      4 0004 
12    28 test_00004     4 00004
```